# binomial random variable-SOA

Tags: probability, proof-verification

Workplace accidents are categorized as moderate, severe, or minor. The probability that an accident is moderate is $0.4$. The probability that an accident is severe is $0.1$. The probability that an accident is minor is $0.5$. Calculate the probability that neither accident is severe and at least one is moderate.

If neither accident is severe then we have three cases:

1) 2 minor accidents

2) 2 moderate accidents

3) 1 moderate and 1 minor

The fact that at most one is moderate restricts our cases to 1 and 3.

Case one:

$b(x,n,p)= {2 \choose 2} \times .5^2 \times .5^0$= $.25 $

case three:

have two sub-cases:

1) 1 moderate and 1 minor:

If we have 1 moderate then:

$b(x,n,p)= {2 \choose 1} \times 0.4^1 \times 0.6^1 = .48$

If we have one minor then:

$b(x,n,p)= {2 \choose 1} \times .5^1 \times .5^1= .5$

We have an intersection since its 1 minor AND 1 moderate meaning the probability of case three is $.48 \times .5= .24$

Overall we have EITHER 2 minor OR (1 moderate and 1 minor) meaning the total probability of having NO severe accidents AND at most 1 minor is the UNION of case 1 and case two:

So the desired probability is equal to $.24+.25=.49$ since they are mutually disjoint.

Comment: OK, then what is your question?

Comment: Not sure I follow the calculation.  The probability that the first is moderate and the second minor is $.4\times .5=.2$, same for the opposite order.  Thus the probability of a "mixed pair" is $.2+.2=.4$.  Two moderates have probability $.4^2=.16$   so...

Comment: Something missing just before last sentence? How many accidents are being considered?